# Restructure the dataframe - dividing one column into multiple and align between rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-manipulation

I would like to change the structure of the dataset.
(I did not come up with code for this yet...)

This is data that I have↓↓

My data below background:

- I set pandas dataframe into series(list of lists), but I guess I can use pandas dataframes as well (Sorry, I am a beginner, so I don't know...)
- **Columns_A**'s data is equal to **Columns_B**'s data (Columns_A=Columns_B)
- Each **Columns_C**&**Columns_D** has the same value repeated

| Columns_A | Columns_B | Columns_C | Columns_D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | X | Y |
| 1 | A | X | Y |
| 1 | A | X | Y |
| 2 | B | X | Y |
| 2 | B | X | Y |
| 3 | C | X | Y |
| 3 | C | X | Y |
| 3 | C | X | Y |
| 3 | C | X | Y |
| 11 | D | Z | Q |
| 12 | E | Z | Q |
| 12 | E | Z | Q |
| 12 | E | Z | Q |
| 13 | F | Z | Q |
| 13 | F | Z | Q |

This is what I would like to make based on original data↓↓

What I would like to do:

- Update new columns (Create additional columns for original **Columns_A** and **Columns_B**, original **Columns_C** and  **Columns_D** can remain the same)
- Assign Columns_A&Columns_B's values into different columns
- based on the longst value;
  →repeat pasting Columns_C&Columns_D values
  →add blank if the column doesn't have any more values

| Columns_A_1 | Columns_B_1 | Columns_A_2 | Columns_B_2 | Columns_A_3 | Columns_B_3 | Columns_C | Columns_D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2 | B | 3 | C | X | Y |
| 1 | A | 2 | B | 3 | C | X | Y |
| 1 | A | Blacnk | Blacnk | 3 | C | X | Y |
| Blacnk | Blacnk | Blacnk | Blacnk | 3 | C | X | Y |
| 11 | D | 12 | E | 13 | F | Z | Q |
| Blank | Blank | 12 | E | 13 | F | Z | Q |
| Blank | Blank | 12 | E | Blank | Blank | Z | Q |

I am thinking if I can use "loop & condition" approach, since the data is list of lists. (Sorry I put the example data as dataset just to make it easier to read)

Please let me know if my explanation does not make sense.
Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a complex [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html). You first need to set helper columns.

*NB. I named the columns A/B/C/D for clarity*:

```
g = df.groupby(['C', 'D'], as_index=False, group_keys=False)

out = (df
 .assign(idx2=g.apply(lambda g: g.groupby(['A', 'B']).cumcount()),
         col=g.apply(lambda g: g.groupby(['A', 'B']).ngroup().add(1))
        )
 .pivot(index=['C', 'D', 'idx2'], columns='col')
 .pipe(lambda d: d.set_axis(d.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}'), axis=1))
 .reset_index(['C', 'D'])
)
```

output:

```
      C  D   A_1   A_2   A_3  B_1  B_2  B_3
idx2                                       
0     X  Y   1.0   2.0   3.0    A    B    C
1     X  Y   1.0   2.0   3.0    A    B    C
2     X  Y   1.0   NaN   3.0    A  NaN    C
3     X  Y   NaN   NaN   3.0  NaN  NaN    C
0     Z  Q  11.0  12.0  13.0    D    E    F
1     Z  Q   NaN  12.0  13.0  NaN    E    F
2     Z  Q   NaN  12.0   NaN  NaN    E  NaN
```